# Greatest Common Divisor of two binary polynomials

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, binary

How can I find the GCD of $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$ and $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$?

I know that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$, and that it is not primitive, but I don't know if that helps me in any way?

Comment: If you know that one of the polynomials is irreducible, that narrows down the answer quite a bit, doesn't it?

Comment: That's what I originally thought. Does that mean that X^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 is the gcd? I just feel like that's too easy

Comment: (1) In your question you wrote $x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ which is not irreducible. If you meant $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ (which is irreducible) you should edit the question. (2) If $f(x)$ is irreducible, then the GCD of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is **either** $1$ or $f(x)$. So you only need one division to find out if $g(x)$ is divisible by $f(x)$, i.e., the first step of the Euclidean algorithm. (3) Of course the Euclidean algorithm will find the GCD **without** knowing anything about the irreducibility or factorization of either of the polynomials. If this is an exercise on the Euclidean algorithm you should use it.

Comment: I meant x^4+x^3+x^2+1. So the answer would be 1 then, right?

Comment: Why do you think $x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ is irreducible? I don't believe it is, and I don't believe the GCD is $1$. **Why don't you just use the Euclidean algorithm?**

Answer (score 2):

Use Euclid's algorithm in the usual way.  The first step is
$$(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1)=(x^2)(x^4+x^3+x^2+1)+(x^3+1)$$
and the next will look like
$$(x^4+x^3+x^2+1)=(\cdots)(x^3+1)+(\cdots)\ .$$

Comment: would the next step be (1)(x^3 + 1) + (x^4 + x^2) then?

Comment: No, because the remainder must have degree less than the divisor: $x^4+x^2$ does not have degree less than $x^3+1$.

Comment: So if our equation read a(x)s(x) + r(x), how do you figure out what a(x) is supposed to be? I understand that s(x) is going to be the previous r(x), but I never know how to get a(x)

Comment: You just divide $x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ by $x^3+1$ and so on.  If you have not learnt how to do this, search for "polynomial division" online and you will get any number of explanations and tutorials.